# Regex for filtering out the groups and if there is specific string in the group then extract that into another group

Tags: regex, regex-group

Hi I am trying to match 3 logs with regex the issue I face is that it is not dynamic as if the value changes then regex do not work on that group.

I think the practical will give better understanding. https://regex101.com/r/sdoZaH/1

1. In this, Group 1 `<address` is working on 1st log line only, it is not able to identify string in 2nd line
2. In `<message>` group also, I want if there is **IP addr** then it should be separate group else it has covered the remaining part of it.

How do I make it dynamic that it matches all lines.

The lines I am trying to match

```
Mar 21 23:31:19 c10sw1 raslogd: AUDIT, 2022/03/21-23:31:19 (PDT), [SEC-3020], INFO, SECURITY, admin/admin/test.domain.com/ssh/CLI, ad_0/c10sw1/FID 128, 8.2.1c, , , , , , , Event: login, Status: success, Info: Successful login attempt via REMOTE, IP Addr: test.domain.com.

Mar 21 23:37:13 c10-M1000e-SW1 raslogd: AUDIT, 2022/03/21-23:37:13 (PDT), [SEC-3022], INFO, SECURITY, admin/admin/test.domain.com/ssh/CLI, ad_0/c10-M1000e-SW1/FID 128, 8.2.2b, , , , , , , Event: logout, Status: success, Info: Successful logout by user [admin].

Mar 21 23:37:13 c10-M1000e-SW1 raslogd: AUDIT, 2022/03/21-23:37:13 (PDT), [SEC-3022], INFO, SECURITY, admin/admin/test.domain.com/ssh/CLI, ad_0/c10-M1000e-SW1/FID 128, 8.2.2b, , , , , , , Event: logout, Status: success, Info: Successful logout by user [admin].
```

Comment: Please explain what you want to match and what you want to do with the matched string. What programming language are you using?

Comment: I am trying to match the only groups you will be seeing colored. Just that but it should cover all 3 lines

Comment: try `([a-zA-z]{2,}|\d|\W)*\s(?<address>\D\w+)\s.+?,\s(?<time>\d+\/\d+\/\d+\-\d+\:\d+\:\d+).+?\s\w+\/.+?\/(?<domain>.+?)\/(?<destinationprocess>.+?)\/(?<sourceprocess>.+?),.+Event:\s(?<eventtype>.+?),.+Status:\s(?<status>.+?),\sInfo:\s(?<message>.+)`

Comment: According to the lines
device: `c10sw1` or `c10-M1000e-SW1`, time: `2022/03/21-23:31:19`, domain: `test.domain.com`, destination process: `ssh`, source process: `CLI`, event: `login`, status: `success` , info: `Successful logout by user [admin]`, source/ip address: `test.domaincom`

Consider it for PHP>=7.3

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following pattern:

```
^[A-Za-z]+[\d\s:]+(?<address>\D\w+)\s.+?,\s(?<time>\d+\/\d+\/\d+\-\d+\:\d+\:\d+).+?\s\w+\/.+?\/(?<domain>.+?)\/(?<destinationprocess>.+?)\/(?<sourceprocess>.+?),.+Event:\s(?<eventtype>.+?),.+Status:\s(?<status>.+?),\sInfo:\s(?<message>.+)$
```

Please could you put various valid and invalid strings in the question.

Comment: Hi @Kendle thanks for coming up to help me. I have added lines that I am trying to match. Also I tried your regex but that is not working with all the lines

Comment: When I test in Regex101 I get 3 matches for 3 lines. Please see https://regex101.com/r/MtQ8Ns/1

Comment: No, if you check the first group (address) in 2nd and 3rd line then it is taking the time seconds... not the field as first line

Comment: Tell me how can I match for both conditions `c10sw1` and `c10-M1000e-SW1` in 1 regex rest all is set